# Creating a new opportunity based on an existing one

Tags: custom-button, opportunity, button

We sometimes get cross-selling opportunities that arise from existing ones. To facilitate this, i'm trying to add a button to the current opportunity layout that opens up a screen where I can input relevant details to this cross-sell. In this new screen, I want to populate some fields which should be taken from the existing opportunity.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using URL hack to pre-populate the details, you can find more information regarding URL hack at following blog posts:
1. http://writeforce.blogspot.in/2013/01/prepopulating-fields-using-url-hacking.html 
2. http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/

3. http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html 
4. http://hometeamconsulting.com/url-hacking-for-salesforce-automation/
You have to use DOM Id of field, of which you want to carry over the information on newly created opportunity.

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: this solution is a) fragile because fieldIds may not be same between sandbox and prod; b) won't work for LEX